# How to insert record where inner joined table is null?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, sql-insert

I have a main table which contains several Wordpress post types like:

```
ID | post_title | post_type
 1      foo         zoacres-property
 2      foo2        zoacres-property
 3      foo3        post
```

the post with `post_type` as `zoacres-property` contains a specific meta value located in the `wp_postmeta` table:

```
meta_id | post_id | meta_key | meta_value
  100       2         price       5000
```

as you can see the post with id `1` doesn't have the meta key `price`.

Is there any way to add the `meta_key` with the `price` at 0 in the posts that are missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a left join with insert

```
insert into meta (`post_id`, `meta_key`, `meta_value`)
select p.ID, 'price', 0
from post p
left join meta m on p.ID = m.post_id and m.meta_key = 'price'
where p.post_type = 'zoacres-property'
      and m.post_id is null
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a832e/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `not exists`:

```
insert into wp_postmeta (meta_id, post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
select 100, p.id, 'price', 0
from mytable t
where
    t.post_type = 'zoacres-property'
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from wp_postmeta w
        where w.post_id = t.id and w.meta_key = 'price'
    )
```

If `meta_id` is an auto-generated column, then you can just remove it from the query:

```
insert into wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value)
select p.id, 'price', 0
from mytable t
where
    t.post_type = 'zoacres-property'
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from wp_postmeta w
        where w.post_id = t.id and w.meta_key = 'price'
    )
```